# MySQL8: xtrabackup Invalid stream argument: tar

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I am using `xtrabackup` to take full backup and send it to another host as `.tar` file using the following backup command:

```
xtrabackup --backup  -u root -p --no-lock --compress --stream=tar --datadir=/datadir --target-dir=/data/backup
```

but tar file is invalid as following error:

```
Invalid --stream argument: tar
```

The command working normally with `innobackupex` but failed with `xtrabackup`, is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

XTraBackup8 no longer supports tar for streaming. Use xbstream instead